# MSAL.JS Vanilla JavaScript SPA sample - error when adding "extraScopesToConsent"

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have followed MS sample ["MSAL.JS Vanilla JavaScript SPA"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa) and it works fine
until I extend it with **extraScopesToConsent**

```
const loginRequest = {
      scopes: ["openid", "profile", "User.Read"],
      extraScopesToConsent: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
};
```

I receive this error message:
**AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope openid profile user.read https://graph.microsoft.com/.default is not valid. .default scope can't be combined with resource-specific scopes.**

I have tried to upgrade to https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.10.0/js/msal-browser.js but without any luck.
*Anyone got this working??*